# CORS headers for app both inside and outside IIS Reverse Proxy?

Tags: iis, cors, reverse-proxy

My NodeJS/Express app was previously only served behind an IIS Reverse Proxy and listened on a private port but is now being configured to listen on port 443 of the server.

There are several DNS aliases for the box and one of them is directed (by the F5 load-balancer) at the IIS port so it hits the reverse proxy. I configured the proxy rewrite rule to direct to port 443.

```
hostname.com --> app:443
special.com --> IIS:9303 --> app:443
```

The app serves CORS headers like this:

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

If I remove Access-Control-Allow-Origin from the reverse-proxy's `customHeaders` section and put an 'overwrite' rule in the outbound section, this works great both inside and outside the reverse proxy -- in Chrome.

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Authorization,Content-Type,Cache-Control,Pragma" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD,UPGRADE" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="special" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="special.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:443/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Set-Access-Control-Allow-Origin" stopProcessing="false">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Origin" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="*" replace="true" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now, here's the problem.  When accessing the `special` site via IE, I get all kindsa CORS errors that stop the app from working. In order to make the app work via IE through reverse-proxy, it seems that I **must** include `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` to the IIS `customHeaders` section (in addition to the added headers and methods). Of course, this also breaks the app so I have to *remove* the same header from inside the app.  Now, the app doesn't work outside the reverse proxy!

Is there a known way to allow an app to present CORS headers and for the IIS Reverse Proxy to just pass requests for them through and back? Is there a way to trap `preflight` and send the right things to IE? Why isn't the outbound rule being hit for OPTIONS requests?

Bottom line: How can I let my app be accessed both inside and outside the proxy and make IE happy when it hits the proxy?

Comment: It may be caused by the version of IE, please check your version of IE and upgrade it to the latest version.

Comment: It's IE11 and I don't have control over the corporate app certification process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the setting for "Access data sources across domains" to Enabled.

1. In Internet Explorer, click Tools > Internet Options to open the
   Internet Options window.
2. On the Security tab, click the Local intranet zone and then click
   Custom level to open the Security Settings - Local Intranet Zone
   window.
3. Under the Miscellaneous setting Access data sources across domains,
   click Enable.

[image]

Comment: My question is more about how to allow IIS Reverse Proxy access to client-facing apps because that one CORS header rejects multiple values and the outbound rule is not hit for pre-flight/options requests. :-\

Comment: Isn't your app working in chrome, but when you access the site via IE you get the CORS errors?

Comment: Yes, but the solution would be to get IIS to send the headers consistently for both preflight and content requests.